# How filetype plugin on changes loading

Tags: vim

What occurs when the `filetype plugin` option is changed? For example, from the docs it says:

> When loading filetype plugins has been enabled `:filetype-plugin-on`, options
>   will be set and mappings defined.

Does this mean that if filetype plugin is `off`, then vim will not add certain directories to the vim runtime? Or what exactly does this parameter do, I'm a bit confused?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if `:h filetype-plugin-off` answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this command does, it simply loads a relevant script from `$VIMRUNTIME`.

For `filetype plugin on` it's `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin.vim`; for `filetype plugin off` it's `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugof.vim`; for `filetype off` it's `$VIMRUNTIME/ftoff.vim`, and so on.

Basically `ftoff.vim` clears `filetypedetect` auto-group (the one which traps `BufRead`); and `ftplugof.vim` clears `filetypeplugin` group (then one which traps `FileType`).

I suggest to everyone who is interested in internals to explore the code himself. The source worth a thousand words.

Comment: thanks, could you please include a link to the code where that's relevant (I think github as a Vim repository). Is the code in vimscript or C?

Comment: also, is there any reason at all where you would want to not include `filetype plugin on`? It seems like from what you've described it's almost like a required setting to have on.

Comment: @David542 (a) These scripts are a part of Vim runtime, so they all are already installed to your hdd/ssd (b) Vim has, to say the least, very conservative defaults. Just get used to it. Say, in Neovim filetype is on by default.